# die(json_encode)) redirects to a page displaying json data

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, ajax

When form submission finishes, the page DISPLAYS the raw json data instead of logging it to the console. The php and html code are both on the same page so I wasn't expecting the page to change at all.

POST

```
jQuery(function($) {
  $("#idSearch").submit(function(event) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/index.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        dataType: "json",
        sucess: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    })
  })
});
```

php form handling

```
<?php 
if (isset($_POST['orderId'])){
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    require 'private/database.php';

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM form";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

    $data = array();
    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            $data[] = $row;
        }
    }
    die(json_encode($data));
}
?><!DOCTYPE html>
```

I've implemented something similar on another webpage but it works as I intended.

POST

```
function loadInfo() {
    jQuery(function($) {
        $.ajax({
            method: "POST",
            url: "/admin.php",
            data: {loadInfo: 1},
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data) {
                console.log(data);
                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    setMarker(data, i, "red");
                    printInfo(data, i);
                }
            }
        })
    });
}
```

php form handling

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['loadInfo'])){
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    require 'private/database.php';

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM form";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

    $data = array();
    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            $data[] = $row;
        }
    }
    die(json_encode($data));
}
?><!DOCTYPE html>
```

Why do these two pages behave differently?

Comment: Also in your second example, you are using `method` property when you really want to be using the `type` property. Most likely that second one is actually sending a `get` request.

Answer (score 2):

You should stop the default form event.
The browser continue the action and submit the form, so the page is reloaded using POST.

You could prevent using [`Event.preventDefault()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault)

```
jQuery(function($) {
  $("#idSearch").submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault(); // << ADD
    $.ajax({
        url: "/index.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) { // << Here 'success' not 'sucess'.
            console.log(data);
        }
    })
  })
});
```

Comment: not sure why but the form does not seem to be submitting now. i added an echo to the if statement in the php code but it did not get executed. there are no error messages either

Comment: What is the result of the 'network' tab ? What is the HTTP status of the request and what if the raw contents ?

Comment: 200 OK. The data that its supposed to return looks fine too. So the problem might be with my php code? I remember having trouble with this line before on the other page. "die(json_encode($data));"

Comment: I prefer use something like this : `header('Content-Type: text/plain; chaset=UTF-8');echo json_encode($data);exit(0);`, and... oh I found something : a typo : `success` vs `sucess` - I've updated the answer.

Comment: thanks for spotting that! but it still isnt working for some reason haha, ill try again tomorrow

Answer (score 0):

solved:

```
<form action="index.php" method="POST" id="idSearch">
  <input type="text" name="orderId" placeholder="訂單號瑪" required><br>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

I didn't think I needed an action parameter for the form as it was being sent to the same .php? The code worked once I added a path. Weird.